# Struggling with MySQL character set, collation

Tags: mysql, linux

I am facing problems with inserting Spanish characters from my application.

When I am inserting on the DB the characters are inserting properly, but when I am trying passing the same data in from the application, the data stored in the table isn't correct.

For example, when I insert directly on DB server:

```
CREATE TABLE  prod_inns(`prod_name` varchar(100) COLLATE latin1_bin DEFAULT NULL)

insert into prod_inns values(Otoño);
```

I see this:

```
select * from prod_inns ;

+-------------+
| prod_name   |
+-------------+
| Otoño       |
+-------------+

delete  FROM  prod_inns ;
```

However, when I insert the same value from the application form, I see this instead:

```
select * from prod_inns ;

+-------------+
| prod_name   |
+-------------+
| OtoÃ±o      |
+-------------+
```

Here are my MySQL settings:

```
MySQL>  show global variables like 'char%';
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value                      |
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| character_set_client     | latin1                     |
| character_set_connection | latin1                     |
| character_set_database   | latin1                     |
| character_set_filesystem | binary                     |
| character_set_results    | latin1                     |
| character_set_server     | latin1                     |
| character_set_system     | utf8                       |
| character_sets_dir       | /usr/share/mysql/charsets/ |
+--------------------------+----------------------------+

MySQL>  show global variables like 'coll%';
+----------------------+-------------------+
| Variable_name        | Value             |
+----------------------+-------------------+
| collation_connection | latin1_swedish_ci |
| collation_database   | latin1_swedish_ci |
| collation_server     | latin1_swedish_ci |
+----------------------+-------------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

What's wrong with my settings? What should I do to store the data and read the data properly?

Note: I am using mysql-5.7.19

Comment: IN additional to the answers below - just checking, you're trying to get Spanish characters correct, and you're using `latin1_swedish_ci` as your default collation? Wanted to be sure that was deliberate - if so, fine.

Comment: yes i am trying to get spanish charecters and i am using latin1_swedish_ci collation .

Answer (score 0):

Don't use latin1, use utf8.  You have "Mojibake" because the bytes in the client are utf8-encoded, yet you said they were latin1.

More on Mojibake and what to do about it:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored

Comment: I tried your sugesstion.

I have altered the table column charecter set as utf8 but still there is no change in result .
alter table prod_inns modify prod_name varchar(100) CHARSET  utf8;

result:
select * from prod_inns ;

 OtoÃ±o

Comment: Yes, but it was inserted erroneously to begin with. Try doing the **insert** again! p.s. use backticks (`) to highlight actual code in comments!

Comment: The 'correct' fix was to do a pair of `ALTERs`, hopping through `VARBINARY`.  See [_here_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/charcoll#fixes_for_various_cases).  (I don't want to think about how to fix it now that you have compounded the problems.

Comment: i tried with backtick while inserting throwing         ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'Otoño' in 'field list'               Tried with varbinary as well still same problem persisting.

Comment: @Jockhelson - you missed Vérace's point -- backtics are a formatting convention to get `This Look` instead of This Look in Comments (and in Q&A).

Answer (score -1):

You need to alter your database character set and collation as per the instructions [here](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-collation/):

i.e.

```
ALTER  DATABASE database_name
CHARACTER SET character_set_name
COLLATE collation_name
```

in your case, it should be

```
ALTER DATABASE my_database
CHARACTER SET utf8
COLLATE spanish_unicode_ci
```

(or spanish2 if you want Traditional - as per [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-unicode-sets.html))

Comment: Those are only defaults for _new_ tables.  So these `ALTERs` will not have any effect.

Comment: mysql> ALTER DATABASE ecomm CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE spanish_unicode_ci;                                                                                              
ERROR 1273 (HY000): Unknown collation: 'spanish_unicode_ci'
                                                                                                                             
I recently upgraded mysql to 5.5 to 5.7 , it worked properly in my old mysql version.